# fill a column based on each value encountered in R

Tags: r

I have a column of values (see below), where I have either a large value or a zero.

```
A
12345
0 
0
6789
0
0
0
```

What I need is to overwrite the 0's with the last large value encountered so I end up with something like below.

```
A
12345
12345 
12345
6789
6789
6789
6789
```

Comment: this has probably been answered before, but basically: (1) replace zeros with `NA` values; (2) use `zoo::na.locf` to replace NAs with "last observation carried forward"

Comment: the duplicate I linked is *very* close, but not absolutely identical; if you can't figure out how to adapt it, then request here that this question be reopened ...

Comment: something like `zoo::na.locf(ifelse(x==0,NA,x))`